# Javascript for () loop variants

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm creating this element with these attributes:

```
var x = document.createElement('x');
x.setAttribute('ha','1');
x.setAttribute('he','2');
x.setAttribute('hi','3');
```

And then I loop through it using these 2 forms, getting different output each time:

```
>>>for(var i in x.attributes) console.log(x.attributes[i]);
ha="1"
he="2"
hi="3"
3
item()
getNamedItem()
setNamedItem()
removeNamedItem()
getNamedItemNS()
setNamedItemNS()
removeNamedItemNS()
```

And the other one:

```
>>>for(var i=0;i<x.attributes.length;i++) console.log(x.attributes[i]);
ha="1"
he="2"
hi="3"
```

So, shouldn't this be giving the same result ? Why not ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4261096/119271

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are getting everything from the prototype as well. Use `hasOwnProperty` to only iterate over those properties that you have set:

```
for(var i in x.attributes){ 
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(x.attributes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What a wonderful example on when to **NOT** use a ternary oprator. Or, should I say, how to use it in a wrong way.

Comment: @alro Oh does the code break? I didn't test it. I only used the ternary to make it obvious where he would include the test in his own logic.

Comment: No, but it's simply not the intended usage of it. If you're just gonna do something ridiculous like `:void(0)`, you're better off just using an `if`.

Comment: Just to explain the reason behind it and not just complain: The ternary operator returns a value, and it's used when you have to use either value X or Y in an expression or as a parameter. If you don't actually use the returned value, the if is the more intended and gentle way to do it. Either way, +1 for editing :)

Comment: @alro I know, you should see how gruesomely I misuse the constructs in other C like languages. :P Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

The `for...in` approach iterates through all the properties of an object, including the 'native' properties. To restrict the output to those properties you've defined:

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

References:

- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).